# FuelPHP Query builder join on multiple fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql, fuelphp

I need to create a query using the join on various parameters like:

```
SELECT foo.*, bar.* FROM foo LEFT JOIN bar ON foo.c1 = bar.c1 AND foo.c2 = bar.c2 WHERE foo c3 = "somedata";
```

The problem is that I can't find how to create "AND" using FuelPHP Query Builder.

Thanks.

Comment: not aware of FuelPHP but their docs clearly show how to do it. For example `$result = DB::select()->from('foo')->join('bar','LEFT')->on('foo.c1', '=', 'foo.c1')->where('foo.c3', "somedata")->execute();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use multiple ->on with one join. In this case Builder will combine them using "AND".

Answer (score 0):

The way they compile the on condition makes it impossible to set values like `status` = 1

I added the function on_string to the \Fuel\Core\Database_Query_Builder_Join

```
public function on_string($string) { 
    $this->_on_string = $string;
    return $this;
}
```

in compile()

```
       if ($this->_on_string == "") { //yau add on string
        $conditions = array();
        foreach ($this->_on as $condition) {
            // Split the condition
            list($c1, $op, $c2) = $condition;

            if ($op) {
                // Make the operator uppercase and spaced
                $op = ' ' . strtoupper($op);
            }

            // Quote each of the identifiers used for the condition
            $conditions[] = $db->quote_identifier($c1) . $op . ' ' . $db->quote_identifier($c2);
        }

        // Concat the conditions "... AND ..."
        $sql .= '(' . implode(' AND ', $conditions) . ')';
    } else {            
        $sql .= '(' . $this->_on_string . ')'; //yau add on string
    }
```

Do expose your method to Database_Query_Builder_Select as well.

```
    public function on_string($string)
{
    $this->_last_join->on_string($string);

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's required Tan Shun Yau.
You can select based on strings but you will need to escape the value's like so :

`->on('t.object_property', '=', \DB::quote($property));`